# Windows 8 - can not right click on wireless network to change WEP key

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, permissions, wep

I need to change the WEP key on my Windows8 laptop.

The typical instructions are to open the list of wireless connections (Control Panel=>Network and Internet=>Connect to a Network), and right-click on your connection to open connection properties.

**When I do that, right-clicking on my WLAN does nothing at all** (left clicking merely opens a panel with 1 option, "connect automatically).

I suspect this may be permissions related, but I only have 1 user on this laptop, and it is Admin user.

Hardware is Toshiba laptop with Realtek WLAN chip (RTL8188CE).

Adding the connection from "Network and Sharing Center"=>""Set up a new connection"=>"Manually connect" doesn't work since I already have that network as existing, so it offers "choose a different name" (not what I need) or "Use existing network" (small font link to "Connect to a network dialog") - the latter does NOT work when clicked (nothing happens).

What are my next best steps to troubleshoot?

Comment: As a side note - to check if it was just an account with corrupted perms, I used it to create a brand new Administrator account. The new account can't right click on wireless networks either.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you see after clicking *Connect to a Network*?

Comment: @gronostaj - Absolutely nothing happens as user #1 (It's as if I didn't click. No error message. No delay/freezing. No activity). As user #2 (also admin), closes this dialog (no error etc..) and returns back to Network and Sharing Center

Answer (score 2):

Different behavior on two accounts suggests that there's a problem with some system components. You can try to fix it by typing `cmd` in the Start screen, right-clicking the item that appears and choosing *Run as Administrator*. An elevated command prompt will open, type `sfc /scannow` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Wait until the scan is complete.

Then you should be able to access connection's properties this way: click the network icon in the notification area (it's a signal strength indicator icon if Wi-Fi is enabled). A pane with connection list will open. Right-click a connection there and choose *Properties*.

Comment: Sorry, didn't fix it. I ended up re-installing