# Windows 8 - Missing right click menu in List of Wireless Networks

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I've recently installed a fresh install of Windows 8 Pro, and am having trouble managing my wireless networks due to nothing happening when I right click any given item in the wireless network list.

Basically, when I open the list over wireless network and left click, the usual "connect" button appears etc. But upon right clicking the same network, nothing will happen. The system doesn't hang, nor is anything else wrong, except for the fact that nothing happens.

I have tried running `sfc /scannow` which returned with no errors.

So, anybody know what might be wrong?

Comment: I am aware that a similar question already exists [here](http://superuser.com/questions/591816/windows-8-can-not-right-click-on-wireless-network-to-change-wep-key), but he has a different approach to why he needs the menu (which can be solved with `netsh` in cmd), and nobody has given an answer in the last 3 months that addresses the main problem. Due to lack of reputation, I'm not either able to upvote the question.

Comment: Did you verify the integrity of your system as suggested by gronostaj?

Comment: if i click on system tray on the network symbol the right flyout with the wireless networks slides in. do you think in this view must be the right click?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, as you can see in my post, i tried running `sfc /scannow`, witch returned a message saying everything was as it was supposed to be.

Comment: @Martin Yes, in this list of wireless networks, there is the possibility of right clicking (or long touch if you have a touch screen) to access the menu for more options. It seems like you are missing the function too? You can read more about this function in Windows 8 [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-8/manage-wireless-network-profiles)!

Comment: @cazyius - I missed that statement.  What does "basically ok" mean exactly?  Unless it returned no errors then we have to address that.

Comment: Sorry @Ramhound, I meant that it returned with no errors. Just can't remember exactly what it said. Everything is working perfectly, except for this one problem.

Comment: @cazyius sorry for asking again [did you mean this view](http://1.1.1.4/bmi/www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/network/wireless/services/owl/vpn/windows8/4_OWL_Win8_Metro_WirelessSelection.png) or [this view](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/ff847520.Davies_CG_0710_Fig6(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg)

Comment: @Martin The [first one](http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/network/wireless/services/owl/vpn/windows8/4_OWL_Win8_Metro_WirelessSelection.png). If one would right click (or long touch) one of the listed networks, an option menu will appear. This option menu doesn't appear for me. (The [second picture](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/ff847520.Davies_CG_0710_Fig6(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg), as you probably know, doesn't excist in Windows 8, making managing Wireless networks a little more complicated)

Comment: @cazyius - then i have the same problem. no menu on right clicking.

Comment: Maybe your system was updated to 8.1 and this option has been moved to Change PC settings -> Network.

Answer (score 0):

You can't right-click on Wireless networks in Windows 8, the feature just isn't there.

If instead, you right-click on the wireless icon in the taskbar, then choose 'Open Network and Sharing Centre' you will be able to choose 'Manage wireless networks on the left hand side.

Hope that's cleared this up.